# Jquery readonly text box invisible on post to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

If the user clicks the use above address the value is set in Address1 and is disabled.
The value is not passed in the form submit but I can get it from the model.Address in the Controller. If ModelState.IsValid  is not valid I get the field model.Address1 back empty how can I populate it with model.Address?

```
View
$("#MailAddressAsAbove").click(function () {
   if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
      $('#Address1').attr("disabled", true);
   }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enquiry(PersonViewModel model)
{
   if (model.MailAddressAsAbove)
   {
      model.Address1 = model.Address;
   }

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return Enquiry();
   }
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to correct me if I cannot get what you want to ask.

Firstly, all disabled form elements will not be included in the form submit.
But readonly element will be included.

So may be you can try to use readonly instead of disabed attribute?

```
$("#MailAddressAsAbove").click(function () {
   if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
      $('#Address1').attr("readonly", "readonly");
   }
}
```